# Using jQuery's clone instead of replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the code below to replace `.div1` with `.div2`.

`$('.div1').replaceWith( $( '.div2' ) );`

However, I would like to create a copy of `.div2` instead of taking it out of its place in the DOM. So I tried cloning the element like this, but nothing got cloned and now the two divs weren't even being replaced. Is there something wrong with the code?

`$('.div1').clone().replaceWith( $( '.div2' ) );`

Comment: `$('.div1').replaceWith( $( '.div2' ).clone() );` - you need to clone `div2` not `div1`!!!

Answer (score 4):

you need to clone `div2` not `div1`

```js
$('.div1').replaceWith($('.div2').clone());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var div2 = $( '.div2' ).clone();//cloning
$('.div1').replaceWith( div2 );
```

or in simple one line:

```
$('.div1').replaceWith( $( '.div2' ).clone() );
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j34j6tbd/)